# error with importing pyside6 , DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, pyside6

pyside6 installed and the path was added but it can't be imported

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using python 3.6, this was the reason of an error

installed python 3.8.2 and it works